# Word for someone who knows what a person is going through but just doesn’t care

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am writing about an injustice for my English class and I need help figuring out a word to match this definition - someone who knows what a person is going through but just doesn’t care

Comment: @Joachim On the app, it's impossible to see suggested edits and apparently it doesn't prevent a 2k+ rep editor from making an edit. Whoops.

Comment: @Laurel Aha, no problem.

Comment: hello and welcome. please note the requirement at the tag for single-word requests: *. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.*

Comment: Look up synonyms for *callous*, *insensitive* -- good luck.

Comment: The appropriate word seems to be "hypocratic"

Answer (score 3):

A rather neutral term would be *[unsympathetic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unsympathetic)*:

> Not showing that you understand or care about someone's suffering

If you'd like something a bit more loaded you can go with *heartless* or *unfeeling*.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few words that come to mind:  aloof, detached, uninvolved, oblivious, closed, unempathetic, cold, insensitive, desensitized, uncaring, removed, disinterested, unavailable, neutral, apathetic, impervious, unaffected, remote, unengaged, unresponsive, impassive.

Comment: Nice list. *Oblivious* doesn't apply though. *Disinterested* doesn't imply lack of caring, it means unbiased; *uninterested* applies.

Comment: In general I don't like answers with large lists because invariably not all the options are equally good.  And I can't upvote because while I may like one I don't like them all. Also, a future reader will not be able to guess which is the "good" option from within the list.